# How to refresh datagrid after using a filter to search

Tags: ms-access

I tried some code but nothing.

```
Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Why?
My datagridview is automatically connected to database,not manualy using commands to make connection.

Comment: What you exactly need...? Explain it clearly and share some codes...

Comment: I used some button to search on datagridview using "Table1BindingSource.Filter". After click I need to refresh datagrid table. Using textbox_textchanged event if I type some string which is in database it will locate it. If I clear textbox datagrid will refresh automatically. No I use button after click and row is still located.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code... i think you except the code like below....

```
//Text box Change Event

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
                GetData("select * from Sample where num =" + textBox1.Text);
            else
                GetData("select * from Sample");
        }

//Data Bind Event by using BindingSource

        private void GetData(string selectCommand)
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionString ="Your Connection String";
            OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString);
            OleDbCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);
            //BindingSource - Binding
            sampleBindingSource.DataSource= table;
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( 
                DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells );
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0 and ms-access database.